# Rearrange PDF pages using the command-line

Tags: command-line, pdf

I want to rearrange the pages in a PDF file. But because I have to rearrange many pages, and the new arrangement has a specific pattern, I would like to do so with a script. Is there a simple program which allows to rearrange the pages in a PDF?

Alternatively I could also extract all pages and merge them together in the order I want. What progams are available to do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`pdftk` is the one you're searching for. E.g. if you want to reverse the page order of `i.pdf`, do

```bsh
pdftk i.pdf cat end-1 output o.pdf
```

Other examples showing `pdftk`'s potential:

```bsh
pdftk i.pdf cat 4-1 6 8-end output o.pdf # use ranges
pdftk i.pdf cat 1-6even output o.pdf     # print only even pages in the range
pdftk i.pdf cat 1-10 ~5-7 output o.pdf   # exclude pages in the range
pdftk i.pdf burst                        # extract to single-page pdf files
```

Read [`man pdftk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/pdftk.1.html) for more information.

To install `pdftk` on 18.04 see: [How can I install pdftk in Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1028522/507051)

---

If you after all search for a GUI solution have a look at `pdftk`'s GUI `pdfchain` or `pdfmod`.

Answer (score 8):

You can also try `pdfjam` `pdfnup` (based on LaTeX pdf-pages)

Example:

```bsh
pdfjam i.pdf '{},2,1-5'         -o o.pdf
pdfjam f1.pdf f2.pdf f3.pdf 1-3 -o o.pdf   ## first 3 pages from f1,f2,f3
```

- `{}` inserts an empty page
- many options available (ex: scale, offset, trim, frame, nup) -- see [pdfjam man](https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam)

Answer (score 7):

You can use qpdf which comes with ubuntu. This following command for example puts the pages in reverse order.

```
qpdf --empty --pages infile.pdf z-1 -- outfile.pdf
```

You can find more information and other examples [here](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.pdf) on pages 10 and 11.

Comment: What's the objective of adding `--empty` in your command?

Comment: I found the answer to the question above: http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html#ref.page-selection

Comment: Broken link @evaristegd.

Comment: Broken link @SaTa.

Comment: Possible the right link: https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#page-ranges.

Comment: Thanks but all links within the pdf are broken after the transformation ...

Answer (score 0):

qpdf works like a charm (tested under cygwin, don't say it),
preserving the links within the pdf required me to
not use the `--empty` option and to
replace it with the input filename:

```
qpdf input.pdf --pages input.pdf 1,4,5,7-r8,2,3,r7-z -- output.qpdf.pdf
```

(rN to select a page indexed from end, z for last page)