# How to run a java executable without java -jar

Tags: command-line, bash, java, pdftk

As `pdftk` is not yet available on Ubuntu 18.04 I compiled a pdftk fork following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028522/how-can-i-install-pdftk-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-shell-version-no-gtk/1028983#comment1675471_1028983) excellent answer to a related question.

This works great, however I now have to type

```
java -jar build/jar/pdftk.jar
```

to run `pdftk`.

I would like to just type `pdftk` with its respective options. I created a bash script, but this does ignore the command line options. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a case for `alias`: Open `~/.bash_aliases` in your preferred text editor and add this line:

```
alias pdftk='java -jar build/jar/pdftk.jar'
```

Save the file and open up a new terminal window (or run `. ~/.bash_aliases` in an existing), `pdftk` should work with the syntax as you know it now.

Comment: I am not sure why you have added an answer while there is a similar duplicate question tagged already

Comment: Can I just create such a file if it does not exist? I would prefer not writing this directly in .bashrc

Comment: @Bruni Yes, or add the line to `~/.bashrc` instead – as you like.

Comment: @Ten-Coin Simply because I'm not sure it suffices. There seems to be a concensus that this isn't a problem, see [this meta question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3608/507051), especially [this answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15946/507051) and the discussion in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here a bash script for you

```
#!/bin/bash

exec java -jar /path/to/pdftk.jar "$@"
```

`$@` is the variable you were looking for. It's all the argument you pass to the script that you pass on to pdftk.jar.

`exec` is to avoid another shell and replace it with java process.