# pdftk snap in 18.04 not accepting commands

Tags: command-line, snap, pdftk

following the simple instructions in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1048975 I installed pdftk as a snap on an ubuntu 18.04 VM. (we need some of the advanced features of pdftk on the command line like fill_forms ).

my problem: the command seems to be only half installed:

```
/some/path # pdftk
-> Usage:
  pdftk <command>

Install, configure, refresh and remove snap packages. Snaps are
'universal' packages that work across many different Linux systems,
enabling secure distribution of the latest apps and utilities for
cloud, servers, desktops and the internet of things.

This is the CLI for snapd, a background service that takes care of
snaps on the system. Start with 'snap list' to see installed snaps.

Available commands:
< long list of snap commands >
```

so it seems to me as if 'pdftk' is registered as a tool in the bash, but if I try to use any of the usual pdftk commands, I get an error message like this:

```
pdftk forms/Form_FM.pdf fill_form /tmp/adsh/2017-4_1532602497.fdf output /some/path/2017-4_KF.pdf
-> error: unknown command forms/Form_FM.pdf, see 'snap help'
```

(this also happens with every other command I tried)
so, how do I pass the commands and parameter to pdftk without snap trying to grab the parameter for itself?

edit: some diagnostics:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/pdftk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jul 11 18:17 /usr/local/bin/pdftk -> /snap/bin/pdftk-smoser.pdftk

snap list pdftk 
error: no matching snaps installed

snap list pdftk-smoser
Name          Version  Rev  Tracking  Developer  Notes
pdftk-smoser  2.02-4   18   stable    smoser     -
```

hmmm...seems like I followed the older version of the answer, which had an additional step that symlinked /snap/bin/pdftk-smoser.pdftk to /usr/local/bin/pdftk

Comment: Hi cypherabe! Welcome to askUbuntu! The third argument of your command is **/tmp/adsh/2017-4_1532602497.fdf**, but it should be **/tmp/adsh/2017-4_1532602497.pdf** (misspelled **pdf**)

Comment: Hmm... it actually looks like you're getting the usage information for the `snap` command (but with the command name `pdftk`), rather than that of the `pdftk` command itself - I wonder what could have gone wrong? Did you by any chance make a symbolic link?

Comment: ... can you add the output of `type -a pdftk` please?

Comment: @steeldriver type -a pdftk -> 
`pdftk is /usr/local/bin/pdftk` yes, I am wondering too. first time I use a snap, the examples seemed just so simple...

Comment: @abu_bua: thanks, but no, that's correct, .fdf files are datafiles to fill in a pdf formular (the call works with normal pdftk on ubuntu 16.04 machines)

Comment: @cypherabe my *guess* is that `/usr/local/bin/pdftk` is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/snap` (which *should* work, provided the pdftk snap is present). Please [edit] your question to include `ls -l /usr/local/bin/pdftk` and `snap list pdftk`

Comment: updated: yes, there is a symlink, i guess snap has a problem with it somehow

Comment: I don't know why that *wouldn't* work, however it's a more complicated than it needs to be - the snap is now available as plain `pdftk` and `/snap/bin` has been part of the default Ubuntu `PATH` for some time now - I suggest you remove both the symlink and the `pdftk-smoser` snap and `snap install pdftk` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As steeldriver suggested, I ended up with removing the symlink, removing the pdftk-smoser snap, then installing the pdftk snap and finally creating a new symlink for /usr/local/bin/pdftk to /snap/bin/pdftk

now a call to `pdftk` on the commandline brings up the pdftk usage hint, not something snap related

a caveat: I still can't access my pdf files, but at least I get pdftk error messages now. I'm not sure if it is a snap problem, an apparmor problem or a general rights problem...but if I can't find a solution that will be a new question

Comment: You could also try a fork based of pdftk depending on OpenJDK as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028522/how-can-i-install-pdftk-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionic/1028983#1028983 . This worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: As described in https://github.com/smoser/pdftk/issues/1 , snap cannot access files in /tmp. The easiest workaround is to copy the files to your home directory and use them from there.