# Where is pdfjoin (Ubuntu 18.04 and later)?

Tags: pdf, texlive

I am used to using "pdfjoin", a small utility in older Debian-based distributions (8 and older). When I moved to Ubuntu 18.04, I realized that command is no longer available. Where did it go?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Comment: @muru sorry but no, because the command has been removed from the package where it used to be.

Answer (score 8):

You can get `pdfjoin` by installing [`texlive-extra-utils`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=pdfjoin&searchon=contents).

```
sudo apt install texlive-extra-utils
```

Note that when you install `texlive-extra-utils`, you ought to download a total of 200+ MB of package, which is may not what you want.

If you only plan to process pdf file, it is more convenient to install the right package— for that I recommend `pdftk` as it's one of the most popular tools and easy to use, proven to work well in my 18.04 system (which is what I use now !)

To install you can use script created by fellow member [@Abu Bua](https://askubuntu.com/users/790920/abu-bua).

```
wget -P /tmp https://gist.githubusercontent.com/markziemann/c48f74eee3f381308e1482852242a493/raw/4f5767d92e9d8fbd89981e47aa940ea7f2526324/pdftk_installer.sh
chmod 755 /tmp/pdftk_installer.sh
/tmp/pdftk_installer.sh
```

<sub>Taken from https://askubuntu.com/a/1046476/253251</sub>

Comment: In up to data texlive (starting from focal/texlive 2019) pdfjoin is not included any more. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

pdfjoin was part of [PDFjam](https://github.com/DavidFirth/pdfjam) until version 3.02.

It was a simple wrapper script, that still can be found in the [pdfjam-extras repository](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam-extras): https://github.com/DavidFirth/pdfjam-extras/blob/master/bin/pdfjoin

To still use it either download the wrapper script and place it in `/usr/local/bin` or simply add an alias:

```
$ alias pdfjoin="pdfjam --fitpaper true --rotateoversize true --suffix joined "
```

given you have pdfjam installed (for instructions see [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/PDFjam/)), you can continue to use pdfjoin as you used to in Debian.

Comment: In 2019 David Firth wrote that he wasn't going to support pdfjam-extras anymore. https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2019-November/044286.html

Answer (score 3):

Add the this function to the `~/.bashrc` file or keep as a shell script file.

```
function combine_pdfs()
{
    output_file=$1
    files=($2)
    gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sOutputFile=$output_file "${files[@]}"
}
```

Remember to source the  `~/.bashrc` file. Then in a terminal in the folder containing the files type:

`combine_pdfs blah_blah.pdf 'first.pdf second.pdf third.pdf fourth.pdf'`

The above script will create a file blah.pdf which is a combination of first.pdf, second.pdf and third.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

A very small but efficient PDF joiner can be found [here](https://github.com/kanehekili/PDFMaker). I've written it last year for Ubuntu and Arch Linux. It joins PDF Files and images and intends to replace the "old" debian app.
You can find a script (install.sh) that will install it in a second....

Answer (score 1):

I have never used that specific tool, but according to [this source](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfjoin), it was just a wrapper of pdfjam, so I'd use that utility instead. However, for more complex tasks pdftk is the toolkit to use.

Edit:

After reading the previous answer, I'd like to point out that installing texlive-extra-utils may conflict with a vanilla installation of texlive if you have done so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pdfmod`.

```
sudo apt install pdfmod
```