# Missing files after installing texlive-extra-utils

Tags: latex, texlive

I've recently switched from U16.04 to U20.04.

For my work, I use a lot latex. After installing the all packages, including `texlive-extra-utils`, the scripts/programs `pdfjoin`, `pdf90`, `pdf180`, and `pdf270` are missing.

They were available after the installation of latex on U16.04.
Why are they no present in U20.04?

Notice that `pdfjam` is present on my computer.

Comment: 18.04 : https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/texlive-extra-utils/filelist, 20.04 : https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/texlive-extra-utils/filelist and 20.10 : https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/all/texlive-extra-utils/filelist  : Yes, it seems that the binaries you mentioned were removed in version 20.04.

Comment: Ah ok! Then no way to get them?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244384/where-is-pdfjoin-ubuntu-18-04-and-later